# Degradation of PMSF in protein extract while dialysing - safe for feeding to animals?

Tags: proteins, enzymes

I would like to use the protease inhibitor PMSF in enzyme isolation. The obtained enzyme diamine oxidase (or better the protein extract) is tested oral on dogs.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMSF), PMSF has a lethal dose less than 500 mg/kg, but also degrades rapid in water, which would meet my application. (The half-life is short in aqueous solutions, 110 min at pH 7, 55 min at pH 7.5)

After roughly isolating the enzyme, I dialyse the protein extract for about 12 hours. **Is this time sufficient, so that there are no or only small amounts of PMSF in the extract anymore?**

Comment: Be careful with the toxic dose - it is not disclosed for which species this is valid. I would assume this is for humans and might be drastically different for dogs. So we can most like not give you an advice on a safe dose.

Comment: How much PMSF would you feed the dog if you used the initial prep? And do you want to use PMSF to be sure, or do you actually need a protease inhibitor?

Comment: @VonBeche How much PMSF would you feed the dog if you used the initial prep? -> Nothing, I want it to degrade in water while 12 hour dialysis. And do you want to use PMSF to be sure, or do you actually need a protease inhibitor? -> I am relatively sure that in the protein extract are proteases and I want to get the maximum yield of enzymes.

Comment: Please do / show some back of the envelope calculations to see how much would end up in the dog. Dialysis will approximate dilution for a small molecule like PMSF.